# Selenium Automation a new window handle

Tags: java, csv, selenium

So after my code runs a new window shows up to download a CSV.  A window pops up to either save the file or to open it with excel.  How would I change windows to download that csv to a path using selenium.

```
public class automation  {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
       FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    String path = "C:\\Users\\K344975\\Desktop";
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir",path);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/xls;text/csv");
    profile.setPreference("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types",
            "application/octet-stream;application/csv;text/csv;application/vnd.ms-excel;application/xls;");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile); 

       driver.get("");
       String winHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
       System.out.println(winHandle);

    //driver.quit();
}
```

}

I also tried making a profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have firstly patch profile and only after it create browser, and for plugin disable you could use

```
profile.setPreference("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types",
"application/octet-stream;application/csv;text/csv;application/vnd.ms-excel;")
```

Comment: nope added that and didnt automatically download the xls file.  Updated code with what I have now